# I am unfamiliar with using IntelliJ IDEA for Java. I noticed that some of my words won't turn gray when I enter them

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am unfamiliar with using IntelliJ IDEA for Java. I noticed that some of my words won't turn gray when I enter them. This causes my program not to run. Does anyone know why this happens?

[image: This is an example of what I mentioned.]

Comment: _"This causes my program not to run"_ -- how do you know this? What error message do you see?

Comment: @Rob In this case though, the screenshot is appropriate as it shows the problem, though it would have been better to include the code as text as well.

Comment: @Rob Because the image in this case shows the problem, which is hard to convey in words or using only code as text. The OP is confusing the _inlay hint_ with the parameter name (`intialBalance:` and `amount:` in the screenshot), for actual named parameters (which Java doesn't have), as shown in their method call `acct1.withdraw(amount 350.00)`. The general advice not to post code as screenshots therefor doesn't apply here, as the issue is with how the IDE presents the code to the user and the resulting confusion this causes to the user.

Comment: @Rob Sure, with the code only as text, we could have told them that `acct1.withdraw(amount 350.00)` is invalid syntax, but it would have been harder to explain them the cause of this confusion (the _inlay hint_ as rendered by the IDE), because that is not clear from the text alone and would not have been part of the copied code. This is hard to describe in a way that is clear, the screenshot is therefor necessary for a good understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Rob That "sure" is a response to the question if it is possible to post the code as text, the rest of my comments explain why the screenshot is necessary, even if the code is posted as text. Specifically the _"Please reserve the use of images for [..] things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_ from [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) applies here.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right. Woke up. Just like sleep reading yesterday. I was wrong and I apologize. Reversed everything.

Answer (score 5):

These are inlay parameter type hints automatically shown by the IDE. You are not supposed to enter them manually.

You can disable it in the editor settings: File | Settings | Editor | Inlay Hints.

Comment: In other words: IntelliJ shows the parameter names as (helpful) _hints_, not part of the java code. An other tip: acct1.w + Ctrl-Space + Tab will autocomplete, Tab overwriting following obsolete word.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I finally disabled the inlay parameter type hints.